# MYSQL query need to get the grater date values only in group by fields

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am having Table like given below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testtab` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `auto_num` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `seal_num` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `arr_date` date NOT NULL,
    `unload_date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;


INSERT INTO `testtab` (`id`, `name`, `auto_num`, `seal_num`, `arr_date`, `unload_date`) VALUES
  (1, 'contain1', 'AT0000004815', 'CN44178', '2014-11-28', '2014-11-28'),
  (2, 'contain1', 'AT0000004815', 'CN44178', '2014-12-28', '2014-12-28'),
  (3, 'contain1', 'AT0000004815', 'CN44178', '2014-12-28', '2014-11-28'),
  (4, 'contain1', 'AT0000004815', 'CN44178', '2014-11-28', '2014-12-28'),
  (5, 'contain2', 'AT0000000227', 'CG11818', '2015-09-12', '2015-08-30'),
  (6, 'contain2', 'AT0000000227', 'CG11818', '2015-08-30', '2015-08-30'),
  (7, 'contain2', 'AT0000000227', 'CG11818', '2015-09-12', '2015-09-14'),
  (8, 'contain2', 'AT0000000227', 'CG11818', '2015-08-30', '2015-09-14'),
  (9, 'contain3', 'AT0000005297', 'FG1005G', '2015-01-25', '2015-01-27'),
  (10, 'contain3', 'AT0000005297', 'FG1005G', '2015-01-25', '2014-12-27');
```

I need output result like given below
Mysql query result must contain the max date values from arr_date, unload_date
Group by fields : name, auto_num, seal_num

```
id  name        auto_num        seal_num    arr_date    unload_date 
2   contain1    AT0000004815    CN44178     2014-12-28  2014-12-28
7   contain2    AT0000000227    CG11818     2015-09-12  2015-09-14
9   contain3    AT0000005297    FG1005G     2015-01-25  2015-01-27
```

What query i want to use here please help me anyone,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `testtab` t
WHERE (t.arr_date,t.unload_date) in(select max(arr_date),max(unload_date)
                                    from `testtab` s where s.name = t.name
                                    and s.auto_num = t.auto_num and s.seal_num = t.seal_num)
```

This will select the max arr_date and unload_date for each combination(name,auto_num,seal_num) and then check if both columns equal in the row, select it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're seeking the latest `arr_date` and `unload_date` for each distinct combination of `name`, `auto_num`, and `seal_num`. But you have not explained your table's contents so I might be guessing wrong.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1550a4/1)

This query gives you that. It does *not* give the row id, because it's possible the latest `arr_date` and the latest `unload_date` come from different rows.

```
select name, auto_num, seal_num, 
       MAX(arr_date) arr_date, MAX(unload_date) unload_date
  from testtab
 group by name, auto_num, seal_num
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1550a4/1/0)**:

```
|     name |     auto_num | seal_num |          arr_date |       unload_date |
|----------|--------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|
| contain1 | AT0000004815 |  CN44178 |  December, 28 2014|  December, 28 2014|
| contain2 | AT0000000227 |  CG11818 | September, 12 2015| September, 14 2015|
| contain3 | AT0000005297 |  FG1005G |   January, 25 2015|   January, 27 2015|
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am having some other fields(total:23 fields) also in real application in this query not getting correct(corresponding) values for other fields
example id field need to return 2,7,9 but its  returning 1,5,9